# Automate inputs to vim in a bash or perl script

Tags: perl, bash, vim, automation, vi

I have a script, which calls in an external program in a foreach loop. This external program opens a vim terminal to add in my comments each time when the loop is iterated. Is there any way I can automate this part? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: Do you have control over the Vim invocation done by the external tool?!

Usually, such programs use an environment variable like `$EDITOR` to determine the user's preferred editor program. If that is the case (or you can even modify the external tool), you can write a non-interactive editor replacement script that automatically applies whatever changes you want automated. Here's a simple example with `sed`:

```
#/bin/sh
sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/' "$@"
```

If the Vim invocation is hard-coded, you may have to name this script `vim`, and mess with `$PATH` to have it picked up by the external tool.

Comment: That's what I would suggest too. Another - hakish - solution might be to use `expect` to wrap the script execution and pass the required input.

Comment: Thanks Ingo Karkat. This is hardcoded in the external script, so I would have to use the second option, to mess up with $PATH within the script locally. Makes sense.